# Way to update existing notification?

Tags: java, android, notifications

Hi I want notification to behave as follows :

When there is no single notification from my application, then there should be one created, but when there is already a notification in tray, I want to update data of the notification.

Can I get current notification OR any other way of doing this ?

Also I am having a single type of UI + data for notification which gets triggered frequently on occurrence of particular event.

e.g. In situation where application is getting messages about score of a match after every 5 minute, so current notification should be updated based on last message received, there should not be a notification for every score update message.

My code is as follows :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.SOME_DATA, someData);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want run your single notification permanetly and update that notification than you have to create foreground notification using `startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);`
And than you can update notification by using same `NOTIFICATION_ID` in which your is case is 0 /* ID of notification */ or if you want simple notification than update your notification with same `NOTIFICATION_ID` and keeping `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in your pending intent

Answer (score 0):

Set flag `.setOngoing(true)` and always use the same `notification id.` in this case is `0.` it will update your current notification.

Try this demo

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView ImageButton;
    int value;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        ImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                value++;
                UpdateNow(value + "");
            }
        });
    }

    void UpdateNow(String msg) {
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("asd")
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(null);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Harsh Shah if have some issue comment here.

Comment: @Shhali Zahid thanks for reply and sorry for my late reply. I tried what you suggested but still it is generate new notification. Note: It is generating new notification when is closed otherwise it is updating notification.

Comment: @HarshShah what do you mean by `when is closed`?

Comment: @HarshShah It is generating new notification when is closed otherwise it is updating notification. please elaborate this  line  `when its closed` you are taking about app our notification?

Comment: @ Sohail Zahid Consider one situation app is running. I am sending first notification, device is showing one notification then i am sending same notification again then it is updating notification. Second situation is now consider my app is closed i am sending first notification app is showing one notification, then i am sending same notification again now the app is not updating notification it is generating new notification.